# How to get specific data from MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I successfully created an online MySQL database and connected my java program to it.

Now I wanted to get data out of it:
In my database table "playerdata" are three rows:

> ID, Username, Password

I created a JavaFX (changed from swing) window with one Textfield(for the username), a Passwordfield(for the password) and a button to login in.

This is my event code for the button:

```
//makes a query in table "Login" searching for "username"s and "password"s
String query = "select * from playerdata where username=? and password=?";                  
//passing query to preparedStt (statement)
PreparedStatement preparedStt = cnct.prepareStatement(query); 

//setting Strings for username and password 
preparedStt.setString(1, userName.getText()); //index 1 for username (upper ?)
preparedStt.setString(2, userPassword.getText()); //index 2 for username (upper ?) (index starts at 1)

ResultSet resSet = preparedStt.executeQuery(); //executes query result to resSet

int count = 0;

while(resSet.next()) {
    count++; //increments counter
}

if(count == 1) { //goes one time if query matches user and pass
    System.out.println("Access granted!");
} else { //otherwise login is incorrect
    System.out.println("Access denied!");
    System.exit(0);
}

//closes resources
resSet.close();
preparedStt.close();
```

So this query goes through all usernames and password and if they match with the Textfield(userName) and Passwordfield(userPassword) it grants access.

I encountered a problem! As I mentioned above I had three rows and this query searches for two rows. I'd like to know the `ID` of the player which logged in into my program. Do you have any idea how I could get this working?

I already tried making a third index (and id=?) and then use the `resSet.getString(3)`, but it gives me an error which says that the index `3` isn't specified.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get your id like that:

```
String query = "select * from playerdata where username=? and password=?"; //makes a query in table "Login" searching for "username"s and "password"s

            PreparedStatement preparedStt = cnct.prepareStatement(query); //passing query to preparedStt (statement)

            //setting Strings for username and password 
            preparedStt.setString(1, userName.getText()); //index 1 for username (upper ?)
            preparedStt.setString(2, userPassword.getText()); //index 2 for username (upper ?) (index starts at 1)

            ResultSet resSet = preparedStt.executeQuery(); //executes query result to resSet

            int count = 0;
            int id = 0;
            while(resSet.next()) {
                count++; //increments counter
                id = resSet.getInt("id");
            }

            if(count == 1) { //goes one time if query matches user and pass
                System.out.println("Access granted!");
            } else { //otherwise login is incorrect
                System.out.println("Access denied!");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            //closes connection
            resSet.close();
            preparedStt.close();
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly. Now it's really obvious.. I don't know why I didn't see that.      The error was because I tried to take a string but it is an Integer.

Comment: you can validate my answer if you if that helping you!